# Why doesn't deleting a file in TFS and then recreating it wipe out the history?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, tfs

I wanted to wipe out the history of a file in TFS for a variety of reasons. (For the record, I do realize that that's a somewhat controversial thing to do). I tried deleting the file completely, checking in the deletion, and then re-adding a "fresh" copy of a file with the same name. However, in spite of having successfully checked in the deletion, the recreated file still has all of the history of the old file, as shown below:
[image]

I have read other Stack Overflow posts, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20784627/how-to-remove-a-specific-changeset-in-tfs-2010) (and several others like this), discussing removing the history of a file (either the entire thing or certain parts of it) using the `tf` utility. However, I'm looking for an easy way to do this from the UI - either Visual Studio itself or the TFS web interface.

How can I do something like this?

Comment: It seems to me it would be pretty poor version control software if it allowed you to accidentally delete a file, check in changes, realize the mistake, and not be able to recover the history after a restore. I don't think there is (or should be) an easy way to do this from within the UI.

Comment: @KenWhite That's a reasonable point - so the answer could be "that's a dumb way to try to wipe out the history in the first place"? Maybe it would be better to try with the `tf` utility after all?

Comment: I think I'd phrase it more as *I don't think it's a reasonable expectation that deleting a file would erase that file's history*. :-)

Comment: Ever try to rename a branch in TFVC?  Bye bye history for the entire branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deleting the folder in TFS will only actually perform a "soft delete". The branch will still exist complete with all of its history, except it will **be hidden**. You could show the deleted items in VS follow this [tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10479797/5391065).

If you want to **permanently deletes version-controlled files** from Team Foundation version control, need to perform a [tf destroy command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/destroy-command-team-foundation-version-control?view=vsts).

```
tf destroy [/keephistory] <itemspec1>[;<versionspec>][<itemspec2>...<itemspecN>] 
[/stopat:<versionspec>] [/preview] [/startcleanup] [/noprompt] [/silent] [/login:username,[password]] [/collection:TeamProjectCollectionUrl]]
```

---

There is not any built-in button or UI designed to quick destroy files in TFS. We suggest you to use some tf command line to achieve this.

Make things complicated is preventing user destroy files/folders accidentally.  Since  `tf destory` command permanently deletes files from TFS. Use with great caution. There is no recovery.

Besides, even though you don't **have to** delete a file/folders before destroying it in TFS.  However:

> Before you run **tf destroy** without the `/keephistory` option, we
>   **recommend that you first delete the files you want to destroy.**
>
> After you delete the files you can synchronize the Team Foundation
>   warehouse. Otherwise, the warehouse will not be synchronized with the
>   destroyed items.

For more detail information, see [Delete Files and Folders from Version Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/delete-restore-files-folders?view=vsts).

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for [`tf destroy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/destroy-command-team-foundation-version-control?view=vsts). There's no way to do it via the UI.

Comment: The poster indicated he was aware of tf, but was looking for a way to do it from the UI.

Answer (score 2):

The [Source Control Explorer Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=HolanJan.TFSSourceControlExplorerExtension-18397) will allow you to enable Destroy in the UI.

[image]
<sup>see bottom item in the context menu</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Since you are dealing with a version control system delete in essence means hiding the file from plain view as the delete action is just another step in the item history. So when you create a file with the same name you are continuing the history of the same file.

As others have indicated you can use `tf destroy` to remove the file with its history giving you a clean plate for creating a 'new' file.